# How to remove items from a Haystack SearchQuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-haystack

In Django you can remove items from a QuerySet by doing this as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/):

```
queryset = QuerySet.remove(item)
```

Haystack [SearchQuerySet](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/searchqueryset_api.html) is build on QuerySet but it appears that the remove method was not implemented. Does anyone know of a way to remove items in a SearchQuerySet?

FWIW I am trying to do a second level of filtering for a client.  Basically I'm interating over the SearchQuerySet for a couple specific properties.  The idea is if they don't have it I want to remove them.

Thanks

Comment: This would be better as a bug report for Haystack. If they failed to implement their custom QuerySet such that it still works like a standard QuerySet, that's a bug and they should fix it.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug.  Perhaps an enhancement but I'm asking because I'm sure someone else has ran into this.  That said I will file an enhancement request.

Comment: Semantics, really, but if you're going to supplant default functionality, your override should support all the same behavior. That makes it a bug. Regardless, without `remove`, there's no way to remove a single item from the queryset, so filing some sort of bug/feature request with Haystack is the solution. If you convert the queryset to a list, you can use `list.remove`, but then you lose the queryset functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/475

Comment: Isn't `remove` only a valid method on query sets for related items?

Comment: SearchQuerySet doesn't supplant QuerySet at all, it just happens to work in a similar way. Definitely not a bug in haystack.

Also, mipadi is right regarding the remove method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using `exclude`? I.e.

```
searchqueryset = searchqueryset.exclude(id=u'myapp.mymodel.%s' % item.pk)
```

Comment: I'll give you credit for this as this what I ended up doing.  (Just way before you posted)

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see with this solution is if the searchqueryset searches through different models. You'll then exclude all objects with `pk = item.pk`, which you do not want to do.

Here's the approach I used. I transformed  *searchqueryset* to a list:

```
searchqueryset_list = list(searchqueryset)
```

Then I could remove the item:

```
searchqueryset_list.remove(item)
```

Although *searchqueryset_list* is not a SearchQuerySet object, I could use it in the templates that render the html page.